# Excel, IF statement, vlookup - too many parameters

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

Can you please help me to simplify or guide me into right direction. My function is suppose to first check if the 7 characters in a word exist in `LABEL` table, if not, then check 6 first, then 5, etc... This is because the table can contain `CHARLYL` and `CHARLY`.
When I put below the formula in, I get an error "Too many parameters". I didn't realise there is a limit in IF statements... is there a simplified, alternative way of doing the same?

```
=if(isna(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,7),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
       if(isna(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,6),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
           if(isna(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,5),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
               if(isna(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
                   if(isna(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
                   "MISC",VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
               "MISC",VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
           "MISC",VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,5),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
       "MISC",VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,6),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
   "MISC",VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,7),LABEL!A:B,2,0))
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you running and do you have to provide backwards compatibility to pre-2007? The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/IFERROR-function-f59bacdc-78bd-4924-91df-a869d0b08cd5) instroduced with XL2007 can greatly reduce nested `IF(ISNA())` formulas.

Comment: @Jeeped yes it is Excel 2007. I'll look into IFERROR, thanks

Comment: @pnuts, unfortunately those are just examples of many more variations..

Comment: @pnuts, sorry, maybe i'm missing the point, I.E. how to apply it to: CHARLYF, CHARLYJ and CHARLYL ? CHARLYL - has separate definition in second column, but F and J should be looked by just CHARLY (have the same definition)?

Comment: @pnuts, sorry, should've mention that also exist something like SMA or SMADV (both have different definitions). And there are more prefixes, which vary in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting IFERROR functions can greatly reduce a formula compared to its `IF(ISNA(...), ...)` equivalent.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,7),LABEL!A:B,2,0),
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,6),LABEL!A:B,2,0),
   IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,5),LABEL!A:B,2,0),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4),LABEL!A:B,2,0),
     IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3),LABEL!A:B,2,0),
      "MISC")))))
```

Here is a repaired version of your formula. You were adding in the default *MISC* paramter more times than was required.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,7),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
       IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,6),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
           IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,5),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
               IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
                   IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
                   "MISC",
                  VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
               VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
           VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,5),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
       VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,6),LABEL!A:B,2,0)),
    VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,7),LABEL!A:B,2,0))
```

Comment: this actually looks like working! (oh, yeah about IF - didn't notice)